# Get ROW ID in a HTML Table to use in a modal jQuery; PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

So this time I have a HTML table and when I click in a anchor that is located in a  tag it opens a modal, where we can change a user password.

But to update the password in the users table I need to get the ID. My problem is, how can I get the row ID/user ID in the modal.

My table is created trough a for:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++) {
print ("
<tr>
<td>".$Users[$i][0]."</td>
<td>".$Users[$i][1]."</td>
<td>*****</td>
<td><a data-modal-id='delete' href='#' >Change PW</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>");
}
```

So when I click the anchor the modal opens and I can manage to get the modal to work. What I need is somehow to get the ID to build the SQL query to update the password.

The modal:

```
      <header>
        <h3>Alterar Password</h3>
      </header>

      <div class="modal-body">

        <form action="" method="POST" id="changepw" name="changepw">            
            <label>Nova Password:</label><br/>
            <input class="textbox" type="password" name="newpassword" id="newpassword" /> <br/>

            <input class="btnSubmit" type="submit" name="changepwSub" id="changepwSub" form="changepw" value="Alterar Password" />          
        </form>         
      </div>

      <footer>
        <a href="#" class="js-modal-close"><input class="btnSubmit" type="button" value="Fechar" style="max-width:100px;" /></a>
      </footer>

      <?php

       //The PHP Code to Update it will be here.
        $query = "UPDATE auth SET password=xxx WHERE ID="

       ?>  
    </div>
```

Comment: `data-modal-userId=user id here`

Comment: And How do I get that ID in a PHP variable for example?

Comment: i assume its in $users ?

Comment: The problem is not pass the ID to the data-moda-userID. The problem is after the modal opens and when I click Update Password, how do I get that ID in the part where I write the query? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need 3 steps:

1. As proposed in the comments, embed the user ID in the dataset of your anchor / row / cell / whatever is linked to the click. E.g. `<a data-modal-id='delete' data-modal-userid='user_id' href='#' >Change PW</a>`
2. Modify the script that generates the modal to read that data and add a hidden form field. E.g. `'<input type="hidden" name="userid" value="' + event.target.dataset.modalUserid + '" />`'
3. In your PHP script, simply retrieve that extra field to fill in to your SQL query.

I hope this is a sort of admin board for which you have proper credentials and security. You might need to check on server side that the user has credentials to modify the record of user with that given ID, as anyone could pass a fake ID and modify someone else's record.